# $slice after apply $in to particular field in mongodb java to search data

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

In my mongodb data base i'm having the data like below format

`"_id": ObjectId("52b2802cd29e32f494463847"),

   "Name": "Hai2",

   "List": {

     "0": "72",

     "1": "46",

     "2": "94",

     "3": "13",

     "4": {

       "0": ObjectId("52b2801fd29e32f49446383c"),

       "1": ObjectId("52b28020d29e32f49446383f"),

       "2": ObjectId("52b28021d29e32f494463842") 

    } 

    etc ..(Like this many data is there in db save arrangement )`

Now what i'm trying is, i want to retrieve the ObjectId list when the user inputs matches the `"0"` and `"1"` position of List key value.If i use `$in` it looks all the values of list.So i'm trying with `$slice` to slice the list and search to particular location.

Query i'm trying is,`$slice -> { "$slice" : [ 0 , 2]}`
`$in -> { "$in" : [ "72" , "46"]}`

If i try and for these two things,
 `$and -> { "List" : { "$and" : [ { "$slice" : [ 0 , 2]} , { "$in" : [ "72" , "46"]}]}}`

I'm getting exception,

```
com.mongodb.MongoException: invalid operator: $and
at com.mongodb.MongoException.parse(MongoException.java:82)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:314)
```

After i tried like,

`searchQuery -> { "List" : { "$in" : [ "72" , "46"]}},

sliceQuery -> { "List" : { "$slice" : [ 0 , 2]}}` ,
DBCursor dbCursor = collection.find(searchQuery, sliceQuery)

For this i'm getting the result like searching in all the fields and slicing the list result field

Can any one suggest me how to `$slice` first after that apply `$in` for the sliced result ??(i'm using mongo-java-driver2.10.1)
Thanks

Comment: I'm working around this like after $in operator using java i'm iterating all the document and checking to retrieve the result.But i felt this is less efficient that direct mongodb query.

Comment: Can you post the Java code you're using please? Or are you using a library like Jongo?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's that first $and that's not in quotes.  But since I can't see your actual java code I can only guess at this point.